# How to install hacker evolution duality games on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: games

How to install hacker evolution duality games on Ubuntu 14.04? I would also download and install additional software as needed.

Answer (score 2):

That game is not free (though the complete bundle is currently 5.59 euro) and it is available on Steam.

So install [Steam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/) and installing [Hacker evolution](http://store.steampowered.com/app/70100/) can be done from inside the Steam software where it will guide you through the payment and the installation part.

[The Hacker Bundle](https://www.bundlestars.com/en/bundle/the-hacker-bundle) has all the add-ons listed with a link to Steam.